# How to make a bouncing form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Currently I am making a so called “virus” which isn’t harmful in any way, except for the flashing lights.

I am trying to make it so my form bounces from side to side like the youareanidiot trojan / virus. I am trying to do this in c# (not the best language for coding viruses) but I am seeing if there is a way. I also need help duplicating the forms so multiple can bounce around the screen but you don’t have to answer that. If you did i’d appreciate it.

I currently haven’t really tried code since I am an amateur at c# programming and any programming in general but I would like so help please.

Comment: This is a deeply UI (User Interface) specific question, so in this kind of question is vital having the correct UI tags in the question (winforms, wpf, webforms, mvc). Also, try to avoid too broad questions or asking multiple questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you're looking for,

I've recently also have done this, but i did MVC in C# and then in my views i've done the following for my form:

Check this [site](https://animate.style/) they have the documentation on this,

It's basic actually, So just add it directly to your webpage using a CDN:

```
<head>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
  />
</head>
```

and then add something like this around your form which you want to bounce

```
<div class="animate__animated animate__bounce animate__repeat-2">Example</div>
```

You can find all the animated stuff on that link i shared

Also follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to get started building your first MVC if you haven't before